# How to create an empty BIG ENDIAN ENVI raster by using GDAL?

Tags: python, gdal, endianness

I got a problem while using gdal in Python. I need to create an empty `Big Endian(byte order=1)` ENVI type raster. My code liked this:

```
import gdal
driver=gdal.GetDriverByName('ENVI')
dataset=driver.Create(r'd:\envi_test',100,100,1,gdal.GDT_CFloat32)
```

But, I can not find any parameter to set up the type of byte order. The output file was still `Little Endian(byte order=0)` as the same as my PC. Could anyone help me? Thanks, very much!

Comment: See the Python section titled [**Techniques for Creating Files**](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_tutorial.html) of the GDAL API Tutorial. Basically it looks like you have to call `driver.GetMetadata()` and see whether the driver supports `Create()` and/or `CreateCopy()`. Following that there are examples of using both. If the latter method is supported, it looks like you'll need something like `driver.CreateCopy(dst_filename, src_ds, 0, ['BYTEORDER=0'])` for littel-endian, and `'BYTEORDER=1'` for big (see [**ENVI Header files**](http://www.exelisvis.com/docs/ENVIHeaderFiles.html)).

Comment: Thank you martineau for your replay. I have tried your method. This is my code: src_ds=gdal.Open(r'd:\big_endian_src')
    src_drv=src_ds.GetDriver()
    src_drv.CreateCopy(r'd:\big_endian_dst',src_ds,0,['BYTEORDER=1'])   I open a big-endian file to get its dataset and driver. Then, I use CreateCopy of this driver to create a copy file, but the output file is still little-endian. It seems CreateCopy not work. Further the CreateCopy looks like to copy the same content from source file, but  I just want to create a ENVI file as I set. Could any other way to do that?

Comment: Try it with `['BYTE_ORDER=1']`.

Comment: I tried ['BYTE_ORDER=1'], ['BYTE ORDER=1'], ['byteorder=1'], etc. I use eclipse+Pydev, and receive a warning said "Warning 6: Driver ENVI does not support BYTEORDER creation option"

Comment: From the [source code](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/swig/python/osgeo/gdal.py) it looks like only the native byte order of the Python interpreter as defined by `sys.byteorder` is supported.

Comment: Thank you for giving me so many advises. I figure it out now though the way is not "standard". 1) I use numpy.array.byteswap() to swap byte order. 2) Open a ENVI raster file(no matter what the byte order is) and write the array into. 3) Change the "byte order" value in .hdr file. It looks like working well!

Comment: Excellent work -- you should also file a bug report to GDAL for not supporting byte order in the ENVI driver.